# Python: Youtube HTML full of BOMs

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, byte-order-mark

I'm trying to parse youtube comments using BeautifulSoup 4 in Python 2.7. When I try for any youtube video I get text full of BOMs, not just at the file start:

```
<p> thank you kind sirï»¿ :)</p>
```

One appears in almost every comment. This is not the case for other websites (guardian.co.uk). The code I'm using:

```
# Source (should be taken from file to allow updating but not during wip):
source_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiYzrCjS02k&feature=related'

# Get html from source:
response = urllib2.urlopen(source_url)
html = response.read()

# html comes with BOM everywhere, which is real ***, get rid of it!
html = html.decode("utf-8-sig")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

strings = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "comment-body"})
print strings
```

As you can see I've tried decoding but as soon as I soup it brings back the BOM character. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `html.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` instead of `html.decode('utf-8'sig')`

Comment: @Blender: That will get rid of any non-ASCII characters, and won't actually solve the problem, not to mention that you're starting with a byte string rather than a wide string so `encode` isn't really supposed to work… so… why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be invalid on YouTube's part, but you can't just tell them to fix it, you need a workaround.

So, here's a simple workaround:

```
# html comes with BOM everywhere, which is real ***, get rid of it!
html = html.replace(b'\xEF\xBB\xBF', b'')
html = html.decode("utf-8")
```

(The `b` prefixes are unnecessary but harmless for Python 2.7, but they'll make your code work in Python 3… on the other hand, they'll break it for Python 2.5, so if that's more important to you, get rid of them.)

Alternatively, you can first decode and then `replace(u'\uFEFF', u'')`. This should have the exact same effect (decoding extra BOMs should work harmlessly). But I think it makes more sense to fix the UTF-8 then decode it, rather than trying to decode and then fixing the result.

Comment: Thank you ever so much! This problem has been driving me mad, since all BOM fixes just suggest removing the first three characters which is normal BOM behaviour.
Just to check I've understood what you've done, you replaced the unicode(?) values for a BOM with blank character?

Comment: Well, yeah, a proper BOM is the first three characters, so removing the first three characters works. If you have BOMs spread throughout the file, you instead have to remove them throughout the file. Hence the `replace`. Same basic idea.